# Problems installing xdebug.so extension on local AMP environment

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, xdebug

**Edit: I've now removed the version of xdebug.so I installed manually, and installed XDebug via Homebrew. When I type "php -i" at the command line, xdebug appears to be installed; but when I run phpinfo(), there's still no sign of XDebug.**

I've just got a new Mac so, like every time I buy a new Mac, I have rebuilt my local web development environment (this time, following an amazing tutorial: https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew)

Everything has gone smoothly until I got to installing the XDebug extension. I use Komodo as a development environment so, as I've always done in the past, I followed the instructions here: http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/debugphp.html#debugphp_top

I followed the instructions to the letter, but I can't get xdebug.so to appear in my phpinfo.php() page. Here's what I did:

1. Created a phpinfo.php file so that I can find the correct php.ini file
2. Checked that phpinfo.php file and found that the "Loaded Configuration File" is "/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini"
3. Edited that php.ini, adding the following lines to the bottom of the file:

_

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=<idekey>
; You may also want this - to always start a remote debugging     connection.
;xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

4. Ran "brew services restart httpd22" (and, just to be sure, "sudo apachectl restart")

When I go reload phpinfo.php, it contains to reference to xdebug.so.

I can confirm that xdebug.so is present at `/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226` and that `/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.14/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226` is set as the "extension_dir" in php.ini.

What am I missing?!

Comment: If you are using extension_dir then shouldn't your zend_extension be just set to xdebug.so, instead of the full path?

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it both ways, and neither way seems to work. Although now (see edit) I seem to have xdebug working at the command line, just not via my web server...

Comment: PHP via CLI (command line) and via Apache are different things, and configured via different files (usually). Also, type "which php" in your console, to try and see if you are really using the PHP you installed, and not something else :)

Comment: You are quite right, of course! It seems that the web version of PHP is different to the CLI version of PHP. For some reason, the tutorial I used missed out that I have to add a LoadModule line to httpd.conf. I've now done this, but I get an error message when I try to reload Apache: httpd: Syntax error on line 118 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215575/cant-load-installed-php-version-in-apache-homebrew-os-x

Comment: Anyway, your tutorial is mentioning PHP FPM. This means you are NOT supposed to load the PHP module. You should have your Apache communicating with a separate PHP daemon through fastcgi... Such a setup is a bit less straightforward to obtain, with respect to the old-fashioned PHP module...

Comment: Thanks :) I'm clueless with regards to PHP FPM, so I used the method I was familiar with. And I have finally got it working! The problem was that I had installed Apache after I'd installed PHP, Apache wasn't looking for the Homebrew version of PHP; when I reinstalled PHP this was fixed. I then installed xdebug via Homebrew, and tweaked the Listener port so that it played nicely with Komodo (my IDE). All working fine now :)

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately this proved be to be caused my me doing things in the wrong order. I'd used Homebrew to install Apache and PHP, but I'd installed Apache 2nd: this meant that it wasn't set up to work with the version of PHP I then installed.

I reinstalled PHP using the command `brew reinstall php54 --homebrew-apxs`, and that ensured that Apache and PHP were talking to each other.

Then, to install xdebug, I ran `brew install homebrew/php/php56-xdebug`. After restarting Apache, XDebug showed up in phpinfo() straight away!

Then I had to get XDebug talking to Komodo. To do this I added in the config lines from my original post to the specific xdebug config file that had been created during the Homebrew install (mine was located at `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini`), and then made sure that Komodo was listening on the correct port (9000 didn't work, so I changed to 9001).